# Read each record whenever Store is loading again in Extjs 4.1

Tags: grid, store, extjs4.1

I have a grid panel with a store look like below. I want to get each record when store is loading again. But not working

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      autoLoad: false,
      fields:['a', 'b', 'c'],
      proxy: {
          type: 'ajax',
          url: 'data.php',
          reader: {
              type: 'json'
          }                 
      },
      listeners: {
           load: function ( stores, records, successful, eOpts ) {
                alert(records.data.a); // fails
           }
      }
});
```

or I try other way like

```
store.load({
params: {
     a: myvariable
},
callback: function (records, operation, success) {
    alert(records.data.a); // fail     
},
scope: this
});
```

But all of them are fail
How to do that. Thanks

Comment: Fails means ? are you getting error or unable to get the value(empty)???? check in backend whether it deliver data or not ..

Comment: records is a data array. Have anyway to get each record when store is loading again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback, `records` is actually an array of `Model`s, you can access the records directly using `records[index]`.  You are using `.data`, which would only work on an individual record: `records[index].data`.

Also note that the best practice for getting data from a record is not to use `.data`, but either `record.get(fieldName)` or `record.getData()[fieldName]`.